# Match Lines From Two Lists With Wildcards In One List

Tags: join, awk, sed, grep

I have two lists, one of which contains wildcards (in this case represented by *). I would like to compare the two lists and create an output of those that match, with each wildcard * representing a single character.

For example:

File 1

```
123456|Jane|Johnson|Pharmacist|janejohnson@gmail.com
09876579|Frank|Roberts|Butcher|frankie1@hotmail.com
092362936|Joe|Jordan|Joiner|joe@joesjoinery.com
928|Bob|Horton|Farmer|bhorton@farmernews.co.uk
```

File 2

```
1***6|Jane|Johnson|Pharmacist|janejohnson@gmail.com
09876579|Frank|Roberts|Butcher|f**1@hotmail.com
092362936|Joe|Jordan|J*****|joe@joesjoinery.com
928|Bob|Horton|Farmer|b*****n@f*********.co.uk
```

Output

```
092362936|Joe|Jordan|Joiner|joe@joesjoinery.com
928|Bob|Horton|Farmer|bhorton@farmernews.co.uk
```

Explanation

The first two lines are not considered matches because the number of *s is not equal to the number of characters shown in the first file. The latter two are, so they are added to output.

I have tried to reason out ways to do this in AWK and using Join, but I don't know any way to even start trying to achieve this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: On file 2 can the column with `*` can occur in any column or only in the last two?

Comment: This is just an example really, but in the file I'm working with it would only occur in the last column.

Comment: Can you modify question to reflect only on last column? also add whatever efforts you made

Comment: Is it necessary to pursue this based on columns? The requirement would be for the entire line to match, not a single column.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR==FNR {
    file1[$0]
    next
}
{
    # Make every non-* char literal (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/29613573/1745001):
    gsub(/[^^*]/,"[&]")  # Convert every char X to [X] except ^ and *
    gsub(/\^/,"\\^")     # Convert every ^ to \^

    # Convert every * to .:
    gsub(/\*/,".")

    # Add line start/end anchors
    $0 = "^" $0 "$"

    # See if the current file2 line matches any line from file1
    # and if so print that line from file1:
    for ( line in file1 ) {
        if ( line ~ $0 ) {
            print line
        }
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file1 file2
092362936|Joe|Jordan|Joiner|joe@joesjoinery.com
928|Bob|Horton|Farmer|bhorton@farmernews.co.uk
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/\./\\./g; s/\*/./g' file2 | xargs -I{} grep {} file1
```

**Explanation:**

I'd take advantage of regular expression matching. To do that, we need to turn every asterisk `*` into a dot `.`, which represents any character in regular expressions. As a side effect of enabling regular expressions, we need to escape all special characters, particularly the `.`, in order for them to be taken literally. In a regular expression, we need to use `\.` to represent a dot (as opposed to any character).

The first step is perform these substitutions with `sed`, the second is passing every resulting line as a search pattern to `grep`, and search `file1` for that pattern. The glue that allows to do this is `xargs`, where a `{}` is a placeholder representing a single line from the results of the `sed` command.

**Note:**

This is not a general, safe solution you can simply copy and paste: you should watch out for any characters, in your file containing the asterisks, that are considered special in grep regular expressions.

---

**Update:**

[jhnc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10971581/jhnc) extends the escaping to any of the following characters: `.\^$[]`, thus accounting for almost all sorts of email addresses. He/she then avoids the use of `xargs` by employing `-f -` to pass the results of `sed` as search expressions to `grep`:

```
sed 's/[.\\^$[]/\\&/g; s/[*]/./g' file2 | grep -f - file1
```

This solution is both more general and more efficient, see comment below.

Comment: `sed 's/[.\\^$[]/\\&/g; s/[*]/./g' file2 | grep -f - file1` (or `-f /dev/stdin` or write sed output to a temporary file if `-f -` is not recognised)